# Powershell script to get the calendar format in Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, powershell

I am looking for a powershell script that will get the format of the excel sheet as below:

[image: tables in excel]

I have been trying this code but i am not getting the correct format as expected.

```
function Release-Ref ($ref) { 
    ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject( 
        [System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0
    ) 
    [System.GC]::Collect() 
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()  
} 

$xlFillDays = 5 
$objExcel = new-object -comobject excel.application 
$objExcel.Visible = $True 

$objWorkbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Add() 

$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$objWorksheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value() = "1/1/2019" 

$objRange1 = $objExcel.Range("A1") 
$objRange2 = $objExcel.Range("A1:A365") 
$a = $objRange1.AutoFill($objRange2, $xlFillDays) 
$a = $objRange1.EntireColumn.Autofit() 

$a = Release-Ref($objWorksheet) 
$a = Release-Ref($objWorkbook) 
$a = Release-Ref($objExcel)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Then why don't you show us that script in the question (NOT in a comment) and explain why the format is wrong.

Comment: this appears to have nothing to do with [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). Please check that you have used the right tags, and if not, please amend accordingly, then people following those tags don't waste their time looking at irrelevant questions. Thankyou.